# How to hot key (Ctrl+C, C) for VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign a hotkey chord e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> to call macro VBA excel. Please help me. I am trying use `Application.Onkey` but can not.

Comment: How are you going to press the same key twice?

Comment: @Tom With two fingers, duh.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: You can't have a native hotkey that accepts two keys; you'll have to implement your own hook for that... lots of trouble for fairly little gain IMO.

Comment: @Tom I think what the OP meant was hotkey *chords*; I've edited the post to reflect the terminology. Such hotkeys work in multiple steps and indeed, would work... if written from the ground up (although I'd still probably want to rip the head off anyone hijacking the Ctrl+C hotkey, but that's a different story).

Comment: Are you looking to set up something like [Ribbon KeyTips / Accelerator Keys?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.keytip?view=vsto-2017) (e.g. `Alt, H, C, P` to "Copy As Picture")

Answer (score 1):

Horrific and bodgy, but you can write an "interim" macro which uses `GetAsyncKeyState` to detect key states and check if <kbd>C</kbd> is released and then pressed again.

As [Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon) rightly mentioned in comments, rebinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (the default "copy" shortcut) is...  "troublesome" - so this will **run the normal Copy action** if you do not re-press <kbd>C</kbd> within 1 second of the Macro starting.

```vb
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Long

Const VK_C As Long = &H43

Public Sub CtrlCMacro()
    Dim keyCReleased As Boolean, timeLimit As Single
    keyCReleased = False

    timeLimit = Timer + 1 'This gives you 1 second to release-and-press C
    'On Windows, this is correct to Fractions of a Second.
    'On Mac, it is whole seconds, so will not always behave properly, and can give you 0.1 seconds to act

    While timeLimit > Timer
        'This will check if you release and then re-press "C"
        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_C) = 0 Then
            'You have to release the key before you can press it again!
            keyCReleased = True
        ElseIf keyCReleased Then
            'Application.OnTime ensures that THIS sub finishes before the next macro starts
            Application.OnTime Now(), "MyOtherMacro"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Wend

    'Default action for Ctrl+C should be Copy
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Public Sub MyOtherMacro()
    MsgBox "The Macro Ran!"
End Sub

'Debug Stuff
Private Sub SetCtrlC()
    'Bind
    Application.OnKey "^c", "CtrlCMacro"
End Sub

Private Sub ResetCtrlC()
    'Reset to normal state
    Application.OnKey "^c"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank but it can not run. I am trying bellow code but can not.

Comment: @PhamMinhHoang What error are you getting?  You need to run `SetCtrlC` to bind the macro to the `Ctrl`+`C` action before it will take effect

Comment: Please see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEDA7Ujm9OY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: with other computer your code is done. thanks you. with my computer this code is error. i don't know reason. -> Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Long

Comment: @PhamMinhHoang Is your computer a PC, or a Mac?  And, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: My computer is window7, office 2013. I do not think version excel or window. Maybe my computer is wrong. It can not use this code: Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Long

Comment: According to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c561a4ba-684d-4040-a10a-082456de76d0/does-getasynckeystate-not-work-in-windows-7?forum=Vsexpressvb), the return type may be different for `GetAsyncKeyState` in Win7.  Try changing `Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Long` to either `As Integer` or `As Byte`?